# AvalonDock slower in 64 bit

Tags: xml-serialization, 64-bit, avalondock

I'm using AvalonDock in my application and have noticed that when I target x64, it seems to perform much slower when loading a layout. When I target x86, the layout loads instantly, yet in 64bit it freezes for around a second or so before you see the result.

The problem seems to be related to the XmlSerializer performing worse when running in 64bit, and googling around, people have advised to use sgen.exe to generate a *.XmlSerializers.dll at compile time. Unfortunately though, this doesn't seem to work as running the sgen post built event :

```
“$(SDK40ToolsPath)\x64\sgen.exe” /a:"$(TargetPath)" /force /r "Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll"
```

produces the following error :

```
1>EXEC : error : Cannot deserialize type 'Microsoft.Windows.Shell.SystemParameters2' because it contains property 'IsGlassEnabled' which has no public setter.
```

I don't really want to have to use the /t command to target every type.

Have any other people experienced the issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well and the only solution I found was to specify the types individually. I found [this article by Mikhail Shilkov](https://mikhail.io/2014/05/21/sgen-to-precompile-classes-for-xmpserializer/) which shows a succinct way to specify multiple types for the post build tasks in the .csproj file. I specified only the types referenced in `new XmlSerializer()` constructor calls:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="AssignTargetPaths;Compile;ResolveKeySource" Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(IntermediateAssembly)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(_SGenDllName)">
  <!-- This contents of this list was determined by looking at the new XmlSerializer() calls in the code. -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutRoot" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorablePane" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutDocumentPaneGroup" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutDocumentPane" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutDocument" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutAnchorGroup" />
    <SgenTypes Include="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutPanel" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).XmlSerializers.dll" ContinueOnError="true" />
  <SGen BuildAssemblyName="$(TargetFileName)" BuildAssemblyPath="$(OutputPath)" References="@(ReferencePath)" ShouldGenerateSerializer="true" UseProxyTypes="false" KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)" KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)" DelaySign="$(DelaySign)" ToolPath="$(SGenToolPath)" Types="@(SgenTypes)">
    <Output TaskParameter="SerializationAssembly" ItemName="SerializationAssembly" />
  </SGen>
</Target>
```

After making these changes, I ran into another error:

> Generated serialization assembly is not signed

This was resolved by disabling signing by removing the following lines from AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
#pragma warning disable 1699
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign( false )]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile( @"..\..\sn.snk" )]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName( "" )]
#pragma warning restore 1699
```

Another solution may be to enable signing in `Project Properties > Signing`, but I have not tried this.

Comment: By passing the provided https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/fcc59e8737982e60c5000d07c9ff2027dd093a6f/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/sn.snk to sgen let it work, instead of recompiling AvalonDock yourself.